# Unable to find an element with the text: "myText" error when using react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to use `react-testing-library` with React and Jest but one of my tests are failing and I think it has something to do with the regex on the `className prop` on the test file.

Below I have attached the respectives test & component files.

Also, is there a way to `snapshot` testing with this library? I feel that my test is not complete for some reason.

```
// Image.js Component


// @flow
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledImage = styled.img`
  max-width: ${props => props.imageWidth || 100}%;
`;

type Props = {
  imageAlt: string,
  imageSrc: string | boolean | Function,
  className?: string,
  StyledImage: React.Element<typeof StyledImage>
};

const Image = (props: Props) => {
  const { imageAlt, imageSrc, className } = props;
  return (
    <StyledImage
      {...props}
      className={className}
      src={imageSrc}
      alt={imageAlt}
    />
  );
};

export default Image;



// Image.test.js 


import React from "react";
import { render, cleanup } from "react-testing-library";
import Image from "../Image";

describe("<Image /> component", () => {
  afterEach(cleanup);

  describe("Component as a whole", () => {
    it("renders the image with a src, alt and a className ", () => {
      const testProps = {
        imageAlt: "some random string",
        imageSrc: "" /* [ASK]: How to test this */,
        className: "imageDescripton" /* [ASK]: How to test this */
      };

      const { getByAltText } = render(<Image {...testProps} />);
      const { getByText } = render(<Image {...testProps} />);

      const imageAltNode = getByAltText(testProps.imageAlt);
      const imageClassNameNode = getByText(`${testProps.className}`); // [FAIL]: Fails with error.  Unable to find an element with the text: imageDescripton. Regex problem?

      expect(imageAltNode).toBeDefined();
      expect(imageClassNameNode).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

**Complete error log**:

```
Unable to find an element with the text: imageDescripton. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

<body>
  <div>
    <img
      alt="some random string"
      class="imageDescripton Image__StyledImage-sc-1icad3x-0 judnkv"
      src=""
    />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img
      alt="some random string"
      class="imageDescripton Image__StyledImage-sc-1icad3x-0 judnkv"
      src=""
    />
  </div>
</body>

  18 |
  19 |       const imageAltNode = getByAltText(testProps.imageAlt);
> 20 |       const imageClassNameNode = getByText(`${testProps.className}`); // [FAIL]: Fails with error.  Unable to find an element with the text: imageDescripton. Regex problem?
     |                                  ^
  21 |
  22 |       expect(imageAltNode).toBeDefined();
  23 |       expect(imageClassNameNode).toBeDefined();
```

Comment: I believe you dont have to do separetely:
const { getByAltText } = render(<Image {...testProps} />);
const { getByText } = render(<Image {...testProps} />);
you can do
const { getByAltText, getByText } = render(<Image {...testProps} />);

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`getByText` looks for the text inside a node. So in this example:

```
<div class="foo">bar</div>
```

the text is `bar`.

`getByAltText` is the best way to find an image. Another way is to use `getByTestId`.

What if you must find an element by class? In these cases, you can use `container` which is returned by `render`. `container` is just a DOM node so you can do

```
const { container } = render(<MyComponent />)
container.querySelector('.my-class')
```

Note that you don't have to use `toBeDefined()`, you can use `toBeInTheDocument()` which is more idiomatic. Make sure you install [`jest-dom`](https://github.com/gnapse/jest-dom#readme) first.

---

How to make a snapshot? Again, you can use `container`. In this case you want the first child.

```
expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot()
```

Comment: I removed the await method within expect method and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

For my case I fix this with **async/await** method.

```js
it("renders the image with a src, alt and a className ", async () => {
      const testProps = {
        imageAlt: "some random string",
        imageSrc: "",
        className: "imageDescripton"
      };

      const { getByAltText, getByText } = await render(<Image {...testProps} />);

      const imageAltNode = getByAltText(testProps.imageAlt);
      const imageClassNameNode = getByText(`${testProps.className}`);

      expect(imageAltNode).toBeDefined();
      expect(imageClassNameNode).toBeDefined();
    });
```

With async ahead your test function and await ahead your component render, it should work !

Comment: but `render` is synchronous so how come? https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#render-result