# React test cases fails in testinglibrary

Tags: reactjs

[image: error]

TestingLibraryElementError: `Unable to find an element with the text: /learn react/i. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.`

Comment: Please include your code and explain the issue that you are facing.

Comment: Use this answer as a reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593805/5618326

Comment: Why using regex , use string: `screen.getByText("/learn react/i")`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).